# Array with Apostrophe (PHP Import)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, import

I am trying to import a list of customers from a csv file.

The problem is with name . For example, I have a customer name like "Mary's Kitchen ". Which include Apostrophe. PHP won't export.

this is my sample code

```
$c=array(
                        'customer_name'=>$a[1],
                        'user_id'=>$a[2],
                        'timestamp'=>$a[3]
);
```

Insert and Update are perform by checking the existing customer name;

```
if(!$row)
                {

                                    $query="INSERT INTO
                                        customers

                                        (customer_name,
                                            user_id
                                                                                        )
                                        VALUES
                                        (
                                            '$c[customer_name]',
                                            '$c[user_id]'
                                        );
                                    ";
```

I am using CakePHP but codes are PHP only. Code is working , only not working for names with Apostrophe.

Comment: Escape the incoming data with `real_escape_string()`, or better, use prepared statements.

Comment: You can use back ticks on your customername.

Comment: Any particular reasons for not using CakePHP `save()`?

Comment: frankly it is a long story.I am using with Quickbook IIF import , so library is only with PHP . I know it is a bad idea :(

Comment: @MikeW any idea on how to use it?

Comment: So are you using cake or not? I'm bit confused here:) But [Customer::saveMany()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array) can really help you

Comment: I am with core php codes on cake . It is an import process.

Comment: @WayneTunMyint I'd need to see more of your code - specifically the statements that execute your query - to give you a definitive answer.